# matplotlib color by pandas group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

'''python

```
# 3rd party imports
import os, pandas as pd, numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

y = summary_df['mean']
# print(y)
x = list(range(len(y)))
# print(x)
groups = summary_df.groupby(['recipe'])
print(groups.size())


# colors = {'2021-12-20_12-57-34': 'red',
#             '2021-12-20_13-03-11': 'blue',
#             '2021-12-20_13-05-53': 'red',
#             '2021-12-20_13-07-32': 'green',
#             '2021-12-20_13-11-14': 'red',
#             '2021-12-20_13-12-53': 'purple',
#             '2021-12-20_13-17-35': 'red'}

# colours = ListedColormap(['r','b','g','blue'])
# values = [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0]

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6), dpi=80)

for name, group in groups:
     ax.plot(x, y, marker='.', linestyle='-', label=name)
#     ax.scatter(x, y, marker='.', linestyle='-', label=name, c=values, 
#     cmap=colours)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

'''

first question so i hope this formats correctly.
(tried to comment everything that i've tried and isn't working but there is a lot more i've tried)

I am trying to color by each group in the groupby df.

The plot shows the labels are coloring individually but the plot is just over writing and not sub-sectioning the plot.
[link to plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heHWB.png)

UPDATE

this is what i was trying to do... thanks JohanC
[link to solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA39m.png)

Comment: Please, please never post code as image, always as text. You are breaking a religious rule on Stack Overflow.  Also testdata should go into text format.

Comment: Also, please explain what you want: a line can only have one color.  Even if you give colors for individual points, how to know which color you want the line segment between them.

Comment: yeah... working on it... can't seem to get the formatting right yet

Comment: You might want to try seaborn:   `sns.lineplot(data=df, x=df.index, y='mean', hue='recipe')`

Comment: worked on the first try.  Way easier and better.  Thank you.